# char *p="abc"; printf("%s", *(p+1)); //gives segmentation fault why?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

why segmentation fault occurs in the below code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    char *p="abc";
    printf("%s %s \n", p , p+1);// abc bc
    printf("%s", *(p+1));//segmentation fault
    return 0;
}
```

here why *(p+1) giving segmentation faublt?

I want to know why there was segmentation fault?

Comment: Because `printf` with the `%s` format specification expects a null terminated string, which you are not providing.

Comment: Did you forget to enable compiler warnings? I get `warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'`.

Comment: Can we please just close all these "wrong format specifier" questions as simple typos?

Comment: ok got it now. Thanks  to all of you.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat nope i am  running on an online compiler. I am not sure if it has warning feature.

Comment: @RajatChakraborty Which online compiler? Most of them let you enable warnings.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat its  programiz.com https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: Haven't see that one before. I don't see a button to enable warnings or customize the flags... Here's a better one, that lets you control the compiler flags directly: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/off9v3ebT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a segmentation fault because the expression *(p+1) references a character at array offset 1  -- not a string.  But the %s in the printf() statement expects a string which is very incompatible with a single character.  The result is some undefined behavior and a segmentation fault.

Below is a fix for this -- we ask printf() to print a single character with %c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    char *p="abc";
    printf("%s %s \n", p , p+1);// abc bc
    printf("%c", *(p+1));  /* corrected*/
    return 0;
}
```

Output -- runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/x7fes479T):

```
abc bc 
b
```

Comment: More like "the %s in the printf() statement expects _a pointer to_ a string"